# how can I specify a certain RadomVariableStream for RandomPropagatoinModel in ns3

Tags: ns-3

I am going to use the ns3's propagation-loss-model to see the relationship between loss and distance.However, I noticed that in RandomPropagationModel,the default RandomVariableStream is ConstantRandomVariable.

This leads to the inability to see the loss.

I've searched the official documentation and found that the RandomPropagationModel class doesn't have an function to specify  a certain RadomVariableStream.

By the way, there is a function named 'AssignStream' Mentioned RandomVariableStream.Although I tried to use it,values the model get were constant .

I wonder how to associate the RandomPropagationModel with a certain RandomVariableStream such as ExponentialRandomVariable?

Answer (score 1):

I'v solved this problem.The class RandomPropagationModel provides an attribue  'Variable' which is bound with its private member `m_variable`.We can change the default value with function `Config::SetDefault` or the value of one object with function `pointer->SetAttribute`.

To find out the attribute bounded with a certain memeber,look the official documentation for it.There will always be a section named 'Attribute' to introduce that.

As for this question,we can change class that the `m_variable` points to using code blow:

```
Ptr<RandomPropagationModel>random=CreateObject<RandomPropagationModel>();
//now the m_variable points to ConstantRandomVariable[constant=1.0]
Ptr<ExponentialRandomVariable>exponential=CreateObject<ExponentialRandomVariable>();
//set attribute for exponential
//Bound and Mean are m_bound and m_mean separately
exponential->SetAttribute("Bound",0);
exponential->SetAttribute("Mean",100);
//change the m_varibule
random->SetAttribute("Variable",PointValue(exponential));//PointValue is used because exponential is a pointer.
//we can get the info which function shall be used for different attributes also in the section 'Attribute'
//done
```

By the way, some .h files shall be included.

Yesterday I neglected functions inherit from the class Object,which leads to my confusion.